# "Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1" can't upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: apt, upgrade

I'm new to Ubuntu. I'm trying to update my Dell latitude 7490 from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.

I tried:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3
```

but I got this message:

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Failed to connect: Connection refused
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Failed to connect: Connection refused
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeFetcher.py:23: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version ('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
   from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
```

After that I tried:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

and I got:

```
Check for a new version of Ubuntu
    Obtain: 1 Signature of the update tool [1,554 B]
    Get: 2 Update Tool [1,342 kB]
    Obtained 1,343 kB in 6s (198 kB / s)
    authenticate "focal.tar.gz" against "focal.tar.gz.gpg"
    extracting "focal.tar.gz"

    Reading the cache

    Checking the package manager
    Reading package list ... Finished
    Creating dependency tree
    Reading the status information ... Finished
    Co.archive.ubuntu / ubuntu bionic InRelease connection
    Connection co.archive.ubuntu / ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
    Get: 1 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
    Obtained 88.7 kB in 0s (0 B / s)
    Reading package list ... Finished
    Creating dependency tree
    Reading the status information ... Finished
    Updating the repository information
    Get: 1 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
    Get: 2 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
    Get: 3 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / main amd64 Packages [129 kB]
    Get: 4 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [107 kB]
    Get: 5 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / main i386 Packages [46.2 kB]
    Get: 6 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / main Translation-en [46.8 kB]
    Get: 7 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [21.2 kB]
    Get: 8 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [8.330 B]
    Get: 9 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [12.1 kB]
    Get: 10 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [3.236 B]
    Get: 11 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / restricted i386 Packages [6.356 B]
    Get: 12 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / restricted amd64 Packages [25.3 kB]
    Get: 13 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / restricted Translation-en [6,812 B]
    Get: 14 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [324 B]
    Get: 15 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / universe amd64 Packages [37.2 kB]
    Get: 16 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / universe i386 Packages [13.0 kB]
    Get: 17 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / universe Translation-en [19.6 kB]
    Get: 18 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / main amd64 Packages [970 kB]
    Get: 19 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [35.8 kB]
    Get: 20 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [3,321 B]
    Get: 21 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [10.1 kB]
    Get: 22 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [1.732 B]
    Get: 23 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / multiverse amd64 Packages [1,172 B]
    Get: 24 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / multiverse Translation-en [540 B]
    Get: 25 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security / multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
    Get: 26 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / main i386 Packages [718 kB]
    Get: 27 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / main Translation-en [342 kB]
    Get: 28 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / main Translation-en [506 kB]
    Get: 29 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [494 kB]
    Get: 30 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [98.4 kB]
    Get: 31 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [163 kB]
    Get: 32 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [29.5 kB]
    Get: 33 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / restricted amd64 Packages [22.0 kB]
    Get: 34 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / restricted i386 Packages [8.112 B]
    Get: 35 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / restricted Translation-en [6.212 B]
    Get: 36 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / restricted Translation-en [2.152 B]
    Get: 37 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [392 B]
    Get: 38 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / universe i386 Packages [4,642 kB]
    Get: 39 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / universe amd64 Packages [8,628 kB]
    Get: 40 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / universe Translation-en [5,124 kB]
Get: 41 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / universe Translation-en [1,326 kB]
    Get: 42 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,603 kB]
    Get: 43 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [3,016 kB]
    Get: 44 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7.794 kB]
    Get: 45 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [265 kB]
    Get: 46 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / multiverse i386 Packages [74.7 kB]
    Get: 47 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / multiverse amd64 Packages [144 kB]
    Get: 48 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / multiverse Translation-en [70.0 kB]
    Get: 49 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / multiverse Translation-en [104 kB]
    Get: 50 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [48.4 kB]
    Get: 51 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [23.1 kB]
    Get: 52 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [192 kB]
    Get: 53 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal / multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [9.136 B]
    Get: 54 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / main i386 Packages [125 kB]
    Get: 55 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / main amd64 Packages [240 kB]
    Get: 56 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / main Translation-en [95.2 kB]
    Get: 57 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [165 kB]
    Get: 58 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [41.5 kB]
    Get: 59 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [58.7 kB]
    Get: 60 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [7,280 B]                                                                                                       
           Get: 61 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / restricted i386 Packages [6.356 B]
    Get: 62 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / restricted amd64 Packages [25.3 kB]
    Get: 63 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / restricted Translation-en [6,812 B]
    Get: 64 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [324 B]
    Get: 65 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / universe i386 Packages [67.1 kB]
    Get: 66 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / universe amd64 Packages [126 kB]
    Get: 67 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / universe Translation-en [63.3 kB]
    Get: 68 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [173 kB]
    Get: 69 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [88.3 kB]
    Get: 70 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [146 kB]
    Get: 71 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [4,520 B]
    Get: 72 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / multiverse amd64 Packages [1,172 B]
    Get: 73 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / multiverse Translation-en [540 B]
    Get: 74 co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates / multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]

    40.8 MB obtained in 6s (460 kB / s)

    Checking the package manager
    Reading package list ... Finished
    Creating dependency tree
    Reading the status information ... Finished

    Calculating the changes

    Calculating the changes

    The update could not be calculated

    An unsolvable problem occurred while calculating the update.

    This was caused by:
    * Upgrade to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
    It is probably a temporary problem,
    try again later.
    If none of this is applicable, then report this error using
    the command "ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core" in a terminal.
    If you want to investigate the problem on your own, the logs in
    "/ Var / log / dist-upgrade" contain details of the upgrade; in
    In particular, see "main.log" and "apt.log".

    Restoring the original state of the system

    Canceling
    Reading package list ... Finished
    Creating dependency tree
    Reading the status information ... Finished
```

I don't know what to do. I have already unchecked all "other software" options in livepatch and tried again but it doesn't work.

I've tried to replace all my sources list but it doesn't work either.

If someone can help me with this, I will be very grateful.

PS. I deleted all the `https://` from the code, because I got a message that my question looked like spam

Answer (score 0):

What about just without the gtk (what is that for, a GUI upgrader?) and no -d

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Background - we upgraded over 30 servers and VMs recently from 1604->1804->2004. Initially I had to use the -d option, but with the most recent upgrades this wasn't required any more.